# Code Workbooks - File not found using hadoop_path

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a python transform in code workbooks that is running this code:

```
import pandas as pd

def contents(dataset_with_files):
    fs = dataset_with_files.filesystem()
    filenames = [f.path for f in fs.ls()]
    fp = fs.hadoop_path + "/" + filenames[0]
    with open(fp, 'r') as f:
        t = f.read()
    rows = {"text": [t]}
    return pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

But I am getting the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

My understanding is that this is the correct way to access a file in the hdfs, is this a repository versus code workbooks limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This documentation helped me figure it out:
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/code-workbook/transforms-unstructured/

It was actually a pretty small change. If you are using the `filesystem()` you only need the relative path.

```
import pandas as pd

def contents_old(pycel_test):
    fs = pycel_test.filesystem()
    filenames = [f.path for f in fs.ls()]
    with fs.open(filenames[0], 'r') as f:
        value = ...
    rows = {"values": [value]}
    return pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

There is also this option, but I found it 10x slower.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

def contents(dataset_with_files):
    fs = dataset_with_files.filesystem() # This is the FileSystem object.
    MyRow = Row("column")
    def process_file(file_status):
        with fs.open(file_status.path, 'r') as f:
            ...
    rdd = fs.files().rdd
    rdd = rdd.flatMap(process_file)
    df = rdd.toDF()
    return df
```